# Why are Java Date objects designed so that you can't get the date?

Tags: java

Why does Java make it not obvious how to get the day of the month from a Date object?

`.getDay()` was deprecated, it is recommended to use `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`

This makes little sense to me and I was curious what the rationale behind this deprecation is.

I have a Date object and I just want the day. It's the most natural thing ever and I can't invoke it. This design is wrong and therefore my code is not working the way it should:

```
private String getIngivningsDag() {

    return ""+ingivningsDatum.getDate();
}



private String getIngivningsMonth() {

    return ""+ingivningsDatum.getmonth();
}

private String getIngivningsYear() {

    return ""+ingivningsDatum.getYear();
}
```

### Update

here's the "solution":

```
public String getIngivningsDag() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(ingivningsDatum);
    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)+"";
}
```

Here's how it should look simple and good without the design errors of Java and using method parameters instead of strange Class methods and factories:

```
public String getIngivningsDag() {

    return ingivningsDatum.getDay(Calendar.GREGORIAN, "SE");
}
```

Comment: this is really frustrating, bizarre initially. Then you switch to Jodatime, and someone ask a question about Date. Same pang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only that method, most of the methods of `Date` class and some constructors are now deprecated. You have to use `Calendar` class to get `DAY`, or `MONTH` from your Date object.

However, I would suggest you to try out [**`Joda-Time API`**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), that will make you much more happier, because, even `Calendar` class is a `bit inconsistent` when it comes to indexing of `MONTH`, which starts from `0` in it.

But, still, as for your current problem, you can convert your `Date` object to a `Calendar` instance using: -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you. I really think I should be able to pass a Calendar to the Date object so that I can get the day from the Date. Anothing else is not logical. OOP teaches us to invoke methods on objects and now we just shan't.

Answer (score 4):

The `Date` means a moment of time, but exact day/month/time/etc is different in different calendars and timezones. So, to know what day is a particular timestamp, you should use `Calendar` `Timezone` and `DateFormat`. E.g. jdk has at least two calendars implementation - BuddistCalendar and GregorianCalendar. Default calendar depends on user's preferences.

Also, have a look at Jodatime library - it is has more features and makes more sense to manage dates in Java.

Comment: +1 JodaTime is a better choice if you need this functionality.

Comment: Then I should just pass which Calendar is used to the Date object shouldn't I? This design is wrong. Object orientation has no meaning if we can't even ask a Date for which day it is.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> Prior to JDK 1.1, the class Date had two additional functions. It allowed the interpretation of dates as year, month, day, hour, minute, and second values. It also allowed the formatting and parsing of date strings. Unfortunately, the API for these functions was **not amenable to internationalization.** As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be used to convert between dates and time fields and the DateFormat class should be used to format and parse date strings. The corresponding methods in Date are deprecated.

Consider also the definition of a Date

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

Adding calendar functionality to it arguably violates the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: Why not just pass which Calendar is used to the Date object?

Comment: Because that would violate the [single-responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - the Date class is purely for storing a specific instant in time. It should not know about Calendars, which are for "human" views of how time is divided.

Answer (score 1):

java.Date is simply used to store the number of Milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970. If you want to have Calendar functionality like getDay() or dayOfWeek() you have to user the Calendar class.

Comment: no no. A Date is a date. It should know what day it is. Using Calendar is just weird.

Comment: Ask your early morning coffee what's in it and it won't tell you. You need an instance of class CoffeePackage in order to invoke readIngredientDescription() *nerd*

Comment: Anyway. Today is a day and today has a date, but you need a reallife calendar to recognize ist is monday (note: your alarm clock extends calendar ;) )

Comment: I like simple stuffs. I'd like if my Coffee can tell what's in it. Look at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#dayOfWeek%28%29 I am not arguing what's right or wrong. I tend to think Date should give me dayOfWeek based on my Locale and popular calendar.

Comment: Nishant is right. Object orientation has no meaning if we can't even ask a Date for which day it is.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is not to find why it was done but use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

first of all, getting angry saying design is wrong does not help anything.

second, `Calendar.getDay(Calendar.MONTH)` is not a static method. To access compounds of `Date` you use `Calendar` class in three steps:

1. create `Calendar` instance by invoking `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()`
2. set your date to `Calendar` instance by invoking `Calendar.setTime(date)`
3. get month by invoking `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)`

Comment: If I destroy your work, won't you get angry? Completely logical would be to just add the parameter "Calendar" to the Date object. The design is totally wrong as it is.